# Vim save file in lower case

Tags: vim, text-editor

I got a new laptop.
And now when i save a file with vim, the file name replace by lowercase name. Any idea on how to solve this? FileName.vhd -> filename.vhd
I don't have this issue with notepad++

Best Regards,

Comment: Does this file exist or is a new file on the disk? Is it vim on windows, might as well see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/dealing-with-case-insensitive-filenames-on-windows

Comment: Yes it's an existing file. And on Vim.

Comment: I look to the other post but the fact to clear the buffer don't solve my problem

Comment: What steps are being used to save the file?

Comment: The files are checkout from svn. Then i open it with vim (right click open with gvim), i modified the file and then save it :w.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot make a comment, I will make an answer instead. This same problem has been solved here: [Vim overwrites filename when writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963602/vim-overwrites-filename-when-writing)

In short: put `set backupcopy=yes` in your vimrc, or type `:set backupcopy=yes` in Vim to only apply it in the current session. This will make saving files ever so slightly slower, but the filename won't be changed.